# cheerio accessing a class within a div

Tags: javascript, html, axios, cheerio

Okay so I am trying scrape info from https://www.jamesqquick.com/blog. Here is my functional code.

Everything works perfectly fine over here.

```
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

axios.get('https://www.jamesqquick.com/blog').then( res => {
        const talks = [];
        const $ = cheerio.load(res.data);

        $('li.card').each( (index, element) => {
        const title = 
            $(element)
            .children()
            .first()
            .text();

        const sildesLink = $(element)
            .children('a')
            .last()
            .attr('href');

        const date = $(element)
            .children('small')
            .last()
            .text();
        talks[index] = {title, sildesLink, date}
        })

        console.log(talks);
    })
```

I am trying to scrape the descriptions of each of the blog post from **card--description** and **post--tag**. Here is the HTML for the card I am accessing.

```
<li class="card">
<a href="/blog/react-router-in-five-minutes">
<h3 class="card--title">React Router in 5 Minutes</h3>
</a>
<small class="card--date">04/06/2020</small>
<div>
<p class="card--description">I use React all of the time and always have to look up how to setup React Router. In this post, I'll show you how to setup React Router in…</p>
<small>Tags:<!-- --> 
<small class="post--tag">web-development</small>
<small class="post--tag">javascript</small>
<small class="post--tag"> react</small>
</small>
</div>
</li>
```

How do I access the  **card--description** and **post--tag**. Here is the current code for how I am doing it.

```
        $('.card--description').each( (index, element) => {
            const desc = $(element)
            .children()
            .first()
            .text();
            test[index] = {desc}
            })
```

The results from this is.

```
[
  { desc: '' }, { desc: '' },
  { desc: '' }, { desc: '' },
  { desc: '' }, { desc: '' },
  { desc: '' }, { desc: '' },
  { desc: '' }, { desc: '' },
  { desc: '' }, { desc: '' },
  { desc: '' }, { desc: '' },
  { desc: '' }
]
```

So it is picking up something. Any help would be appreciated. The desired results of this code would to be able to display all the descs.

Comment: Sounds like you already have all the tools necessary to figure this out: just see what's _in_ `$('.card--description')` first (e.g. console log it or something) and then figure out how to get to the data you want based on what you actually find?

Comment: Yes whenever I console log the variable it just vies me empty an objects

Comment: okay i got tags. from .siblings().text()

Comment: Try `test.push($(element).text());`, instead. `.children()` gets the children that are not text nodes.

Comment: here you go ladies and gentlemen it was this .first().text()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply target with the className alongwith tagName

```
$('li p.card--description').each((index, element) => {
    const desc = $(element).text();
    test[index] = { desc }
})
$('li small.post--tag').each((index, element) => {
    const desc = $(element).text();
    test2[index] = { desc }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like:

```
$('li.card').get().map(li => {
  return {
    cardDescription: $(li).find('.card--description').text(),
    postTags: $(li).find('.post--tag').get().map(small => $(small).text())
  }
})
```